# how to get php session value in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, session

i have a php file in which i am calling external takeatour.js file 
in that js file i want php session data.by using a code....

```
$(this).ready(function() {

    var category = <?php echo json_encode($this->session->userdata('category')); ?>;     
   alert("category="+category);
});
```

is it correct??
plz give me some suggestion.
Thanks!!

Comment: Please post your full code!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: If you are using Static method, Then why CI?? CI have library call `SESSION`

Comment: PHP (server) --> HTML --> Javascript (client). You can only `echo` the value so it'll be present in the HTML to be available from javascript. Client doesn't have direct access to PHP variable, but you can ask the server (ajax for example) for the value.

Comment: The file should be with `.php` extension. `.js` will not execute `php`.

Comment: You need to pass session value from php to javascript file.

Comment: plz  Khushang Bhavnagarwala guide me how to pass php value to javascript file

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the session variable from PHP code to javascript code like this:

```js
<?php
$variablephp = $_SESSION['category'];
?>

<script>
var variablejs = "<?php echo $variablephp; ?>" ;
alert("category = " + variablejs);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `.php` to the end of the javascript file.  That way the server will process it.

If you include it in a page that a client will download later, make sure to `type=text/javascript"` in your script tag because it won't be happy with the extension otherwise.

Whatever editor you use will likely not syntax highlight properly since you will not be following php conventions.

Answer (score -1):

you can pass the category value as a parameter in the src attribute. For example:

```
<script src="myjs.js?category=<?php echo $this->session->userdata('category'); ?>"></script>
```

and then get the category value inside your script.